# If $G$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then $G_{i+1}\leq Z_{c-i}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> A normal series $$G=G_1\geq G_2 \geq \dots\geq G_n=1$$
>   with each $G_i\lhd G$ and $G_i/G_{i+1}\leq Z(G/G_{i+1})$ is called a central series.
>
> If $G$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then $G_{i+1}\leq Z_{c-i}$.

I have searched in google, while most of the solution given is for ascending central series or they prove in the other direction that is $G_{c-i+1}\leq Z_i$ but in this case we can't assume that $G_{c+1}=1$ yet.

For $i=0$, clearly we have $G_1=G=Z_c$.
Suppose that $G_{i+1}\leq Z_{c-i}$.
We need to show that $G_{i+2}\leq Z_{c-i-1}$.
The information I have is $Z_{c-i}/Z_{c-i-1}=Z(G/Z_{c-i-1})$.
Another information I know is $[Z_{c-i},G]\leq Z_{c-i-1}$.

Comment: It's not true. You could have $G_1=G_2$ and then $G_2 \le Z_{c-1}$ would be false.

Comment: The correct statement, as for instance in Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I, should be $G_{i} \le Z_{{\color{red}n} - i}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt This is the question 5.39 (ii)  from An Introduction to the theory of group, Rotman (page 118). "Moreover, if $G$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then $$\Gamma_{i+1}\leq G_{i+1}\leq Z_{c-i}$$ for all $i$". So is there a typo?

Comment: In my 1965 edition is is not there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks! I am using the fourth edition.